# knockoutobservable value update only inside the clicked function but not in the UI in Type Script code

Tags: javascript, typescript, knockout.js

please I am stuck in this problem from yesterday without fixing :

when I click the knockout checkbox, the button will send the true-false value and by the click, event reach the driverSelected function, there will print the item and it works perfect, but I need to filter the selected data with other information, but it not changes is empty

- Html

  `<input type="checkbox" data-bind="  checked:isSelectedDriver , click:$root.driverSelected()" />`

> 

```
 this.assignedDriver = ko.observable(new Model.Driver());
```

view model function

```
driverSelected = () => {
        return (item, ui: any) => { // lambda expression  




            if (item.isSelectedDriver()) {



                this.assignedDriver = ko.observable(item.driver);

                this.assignedDriver.valueHasMutated;

                console.log(this.assignedDriver());




                return true

            }
        }
    }
```

- the result in HTML it shows me the default which empties without errors even when I delete the attribute value ( wbc_name) is show me [ object object }

Comment: You have to set an observable value by calling it with its new value: `this.assignedDriver(item.driver)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning what `this.assignedDriver` is, instead of setting the value in your JS.

To assign a value to an observable, you call the observable with the value that you want to set it to, for example:

```js
this.thing = ko.observable(5); // Observable created, initial value 5.
this.thing(42); // Sets the value of the observable, value is now 42;
```

See [the documentation](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#reading-and-writing-observables) that explains this.

In this case, the fix would be to modify the first two lines in the if-statement in `driverSelected`.

```js
driverSelected = () => {
    return (item, ui: any) => {
        if (item.isSelectedDriver()) {
            this.assignedDriver(item.driver);
            console.log(this.assignedDriver());
            return true;
        }
    };
};
```